# Populate a message on Save Button click and redirect in newform.aspx PreSaveAction Call in SP 2010 List Form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-form, newform

I need to populate a message or a display a dialog box when Save Button click triggers within my newform.aspx's PreSaveAction is called and redirect to `allitems.aspx` page for viewing the latest inserted item.

Is it possible through jQuery ?I am already referencing jquery 1.6.0 in my function and not used the jquery-UI plugins.

I know plugins are available for displaying the dialog box, but never used within SP 2010 environment.

I tried the below code, but somehow it didn't work.

```
if(flagGeneric == false)
{
  alert('please fill mandatory fields');
  return false;
}
else
{
 alert('Valdiations are done! Going to save the form ');
  var msg = "New Opportunity been created  successfully!";
  sec  = 10; 
  Notify(msg, sec)
 return true;
 }

var  notifyId = null;
function Notify(msg, sec) {
notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(msg, true);

 setTimeout(function () {
  SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
  notifyId = '';
 }, (sec == null ? 1500 : sec));
}
```

Comment: Do you wish to show an alert message when the user clicks Save button in newform.aspx? and redirect it to allitems.aspx? you may put alert in PreSaveAction and give return true. It will work

Comment: That helped me. Is it possible to show a dialog box with nice look and feel using jQuery?

Comment: one issue is that, i am having a  detailed status column which is  `Enhanced rich text type field ` and when I tried to validate using jQuery , it didn't work and alert message popped up and SP's default mandatory error message being populated which is wrong in my case.Can you tell how to validate the enhanced rich text within the PreSaveAction call using js or jQuery?

Comment: the content from enhanced rich text field will be populated as HTML content. Convert the html content to normal text and try it. You will get JQuery to convert it.

Comment: I will open a new thread thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display an alert message with nice look and feel, you may create a page and show it in a SP.UI.ModalDialog within PreSaveAction.